# How the page loading is done in this template

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I opened this template and I found that when I navigate from page to another that a progress bar appear and start to load inside the page itself then disappear and the page appear without the page itself reload like normal using of href tag. The URL become like this

http://localhost/devoops/index.php#ajax/charts_xcharts.html

I want to know only how to load a page like this, what scripts I should use ?. If you gave me just an example or a link to an article that would be enough.

Here is the template please test it to know what I mean as I dont know how to describe that.

[devoops template](http://devoops.me/themes/devoops2/devoops2.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic in this template are made by LoadAjaxContent function on line 1136 on js/devoops.js file.

This function was used to: start on line 3361, menu on line 3400, top menu on line 3466 and search field on the line 3475, all in the same file.

I hope you at least know some knowledge of JQuery which in fact was what was used here.

BTW the link does the rest and all templates are in the ajax folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you referred to is so called the partial load or refresh partial views.

There's a lot of frameworks out there can achieve things like this.

Check out **[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org)** and a module called **[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)**

Basically, say you have a page like this:

http://levi-lu.net/#/about

If I'm using ui-router, http://levi-lu.net is the main view, and the part after hashtag (/about) is a route under this view, switch between routes will only affects part of the page (**partial refresh**).